# PySide / Shiboken compile error raised during cmake

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm trying to install the new version of PySide (1.2.~) on an OS X 10.7.5 system in a virtualenv.

I'm following the commands posted on github page however during compile I get this error:

```
/opt/local/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:9:10: fatal error: '../QtCore/qnamespace.h' file not found
```

and then installation/compile stops saying:

```
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Error compiling shiboken
```

How can I install PySide and overcome this problem?

Comment: I struggled getting PySide installed on Linux but I have it all working now. How are you installing it? Using pip?

Comment: I cloned the git repo and ran setup.py bdist_egg to build the egg to install.

Comment: Do you have QT installed?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I have both PySide 1.1.~ and Qt4.8 installed and running outside of virtual env. I also installed PySide 1.2.~ via macports but still it shows PySide version as one lower, and nothing gets installed inside virtualenv.

Comment: Same here. This is annoying and I haven't found the solution...

Comment: @Japboy, found the solution: Macports. Downloads, compiles, installs.

Comment: There is a 3 years old issue about this on github: https://github.com/PySide/pyside-setup/issues/36